# C# did you intend to invoke method

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, esri

Vba code I am trying to convert to C#.  I am getting really close but I can figure out why I keep getting this error.  Error Cannot convert method group 'NextFeature' to non-delegate type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureSelection'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;


namespace ArcMapAddin1
{
    public partial class frmParcelReader : Form
    {
        public frmParcelReader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void ReadData()
            {

                //IMxDocument pMxDoc =  default(IMxDocument);
                 IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMapAddin1.ArcMap.Document;
                //IMap pMap = default(IMap);
                IMap pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap;
                //IFeatureSelection pFLayer = default(IFeatureSelection);
            IFeatureLayer pLayer = pMap.get_Layer(0) as IFeatureLayer;    

            IFeatureSelection pFLayer = pLayer as IFeatureSelection;

            string stopHere2 = "";

                for (int Count = 0; Count <= pMap.LayerCount - 1; Count++) {

                    //if (pMap.LayerCount == "sde.GIS.parcels_adacounty")
                    if (pLayer.Name == "sde.GIS.parcels_adacounty")
                    {
                        //pFLayer = pMap.get_Layer(0)

                       //string thisString = pFLayer.SelectionSet.IDs.ToString();


                        IFeatureCursor pFCursor = null;

                        //pFLayer.SelectionSet.Search(null, false, pFCursor);


                        //IFeature pFLayer = pLayer(IFeature);

                        pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature;

                        if (pFLayer.SelectionSet.Count != 0) {
                            //lblParcel.Text = pF.Value.Fields.FindField("PARCEL");
                            //lblPrimaryOwner.Text =    pF.Value(pF.Fields.FindField("PRIMOWNER"));
                            //lblMailingAddress.Text = pF.Value(pF.Fields.FindField("ADDCONCAT"));
                            //lblPropertyAddress.Text = pF.Value(pF.Fields.FindField("ADDRESS"));
                        } else {
                            //if (sender == "Button")
                               // MessageBox.Show("Please select a Parcel.");
                        }

                        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
                    }
                }

            }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does pFCursor.NextFeature returns?  If it's an object of pfLayer's type, you probably want to change pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature; to pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature();

Answer (score 8):

`NextFeature` is a method that returns an `IFeature` when called (see documentation [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IFeatureCursor_NextFeature.htm)).  As such, you need to change this:

```
pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature;
```

to this:

```
pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature();
```

So that the function is actually called.  The original line of code is basically taking a function pointer and trying to cast it to an `IFunction`, hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need to add `()` to the end of `NextFeature`.

Like this:

```
pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature();
```

Of course, `pFCursor` needs to be initialized to something other than `null` first, or it will crash when you run the code.

Answer (score 3):

NextFeature is a method you have to call it with empty brackets:

```
pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature();
```

Answer (score 2):

This part will never work:

```
IFeatureCursor pFCursor = null;
pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature;   // pFCursor is sure to be null
```

But that would be a runtime error. Presumably NextFeature is a method (function), then you would need:

```
IFeatureCursor pFCursor = ...     // something valid
pFLayer = pFCursor.NextFeature(); // always use () in a method call
```

Comment: I tried that however I can't find anything to replace null.  I keep getting the error. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature' to 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureSelection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"